# curl and cookies - command line tool

Tags: linux, cookies, curl

I am trying to get more familiar to curl, so I am trying to send post request to a webpage from a site I am already logged into :

```
curl --data "name=value" http://www.mysite.com >> post_request.txt
```

I had an output consisting of all the hmtl page with a message telling me I was not logged in so I retrieved the site's cookie (called PHPSESSID, is that of importance) stored it in /temp/cookies.txt and then

```
 curl --cookie /tmp/cookies.txt --cookie-jar /tmp/cookies.txt --data "name=value" http://www.mysite.com > post_request.txt
```

but I still have the same message. Someone could help ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a network dumping tool (`wireshark` or `tcpdump`) and sniff the communication between your shell and the server. Check if the cookie is sent and if it has the right content.